# What exactly does @synthesize do?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have seen the following piece of code:

```
//example.h
MKMapView * mapView1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKMapView * mapView;

//example.m
@synthesize mapView = mapView1
```

What is the relation between `mapView` and `mapView1`?
Does it create a `set` and `get` method for `mapView1`?

Comment: Update: but with the latest tool set @synthesize is now (almost) never needed. See answer to [Other Stack Overflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019798/about-naming-the-instance-variable-in-objective-c/17019883#17019883).

Answer (score 231):

In your example, `mapView1` is an *instance variable* (ivar), a piece of memory storage that belongs to an instance of the class defined in `example.h` and `example.m`. `mapView` is the name of a *property*. Properties are attributes of an object that can be read or set using the dot notation: `myObject.mapView`. A property doesn't *have* to be based on an ivar, but most properties are. The `@property`declaration simply tells the world that there is a property called `mapView`.

`@synthesize mapView = mapView1;`

This line tells the compiler to create a setter and getter for `mapView`, and that they should use the ivar called `mapView1`. Without the `= mapView1` part, the compiler would assume that the property and ivar have the same name. (In this case, that would produce a compiler error, since there is no ivar called `mapView`.)

The result of this `@synthesize` statement is similar to if you had added this code yourself:

```
-(MKMapView *)mapView
{
   return mapView1;
}

-(void)setMapView:(MKMapView *)newMapView
{
  if (newMapView != mapView1)
  {
    [mapView1 release];
    mapView1 = [newMapView retain];
  }
}
```

If you do add that code to the class yourself, you can replace the `@synthesize` statement with

`@dynamic mapView;`

The main thing is to have a very clear conceptual distinction between ivars and properties. They are really two very different concepts.

Answer (score 31):

`@synthesize` creates a getter and a setter for the variable.

This lets you specify some attributes for your variables and when you `@synthesize` that property to the variable you generate the getter and setter for the variable.

The property name can be the same as the variable name. Sometimes people want it to be different so as to use it in `init` or `dealloc` or when the parameter is passed with the same variable's name.

Answer (score 17):

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW9):

> You use the @synthesize keyword to tell the compiler that it should synthesize the setter and/or getter methods for the property if you do not supply them within the @implementation block.

Answer (score 10):

As I just run into this problem when editing legacy code I want to make additional notes to the existing answers one needs to be aware of.

**Even with a newer compiler version it sometimes does make a difference if you omit `@synthesize propertyName` or not**.

In the case you declare an instance variable *without* underscore while still synthesizing it, such as:

**Header:**

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject {
   int someInt;
}
@property int someInt;
@end
```

**Implementation:**

```
@implementation SomeClass
@synthesize someInt;
@end
```

`self.someInt` will access the same variable as `someInt`. Not using a leading underscore for ivars does not follow the naming conventions but I just came into a situation where I had to read and modify such code.

**But if you now think *"Hey, @synthesize is not important any more as we use a newer compiler"* you are wrong!** Your class then will result in having **two ivars**, namely `someInt` plus an autogenerated `_someInt` variable. Thus `self.someInt` and `someInt` will not address the same variables any more. If you don't expect such behavior as I did this might get you some headache to find out.

Comment: "synchronize" != "synthesize"?

Comment: Yes, these are 2 different concepts. `@synchronize` is a directive for how to synchronize threads when accessing the property and `@synthesize` is for binding the property to an instance variable through getters and setters.

Comment: jameshfisher's comment was meant to alert you that you have confused synchronize and synthesize in your answer. You use the two interchangeably.

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of that! I totally oversaw that, I've updated the answer to not use the non-existing @synchronize keyword.

Comment: In that case, xcode 10 will warn about the issue: `Autosynthesized property 'someInt' will use synthesized instance variable '_someInt', not existing instance variable 'someInt'`. (I don't know in which version of xcode this warning was added.)

Answer (score 7):

As per apple documentation [@Synthesize](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) is used only to rename instance variables. For example

```
@property NSString *str;

@synthesize str = str2;
```

Now in the class you can not use `_str` as the above line has renames the instance variable to `str2`

`@property` allows objects to be used by objects in other classes, or in other words makes the object public.

Comment: Apparently, starting with Xcode 4.4, Clang provides support for autosynthesis of declared properties.  So @synthesize is no longer necessary for most cases.  See http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/01/property-synthesis-with-xcode-4-dot-4.html

Answer (score 5):

When you create a property in @interface, that property will be automatically back by an instance variable named as _propertyName. 
 So when you create a property named as firstName, behind the scene compiler will create an instance variable named as _firstName by default. Compiler will also create the getter and setter method for you(i.e. firstName, setFirstName).

Now when you synthesize the property by @synthesize firstName, you are simply telling the compiler rename my instance variable(_firstName) by firstName. If you want to rename your backed up instance variable by different name you can simply assign different name while synthesizing the property name(i.e. @synthesize firstName = myFirstName), by doing this your property is backed up by an instance variable named as myFirstname.

So, in short, most of the time @synthesize used to rename your instance variable backed up by your property.

Answer (score 2):

See [the apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html)

Basically the synthesize creates a setMapView and mapView methods which set and get mapView1

Answer (score 2):

It creates getter and setter for your object. You can access with something like this :

```
MKMapView* m = object.mapView;
```

or

```
object.mapView = someMapViewObject
```

mapView1 is the name of the ivar in the class, mapView is the name for the getter / setter method(s).