# What does this mean in a code? @synthetize x = _x;

Tags: objective-c

For example:

```
@synthesize wheelImageView = _wheelImageView;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly does @synthesize do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266467/what-exactly-does-synthesize-do)

Comment: Don't name instance variables with a leading underscore.  Apple reserves that prefix for its own private methods/ivars.

Comment: @JeremyP Only for method names

Comment: @mustIsignUp:  Technically, yes, but it's probably a good idea to avoid for ivars too.

Answer (score 4):

That will cause Objective-C to create a getter and setter named wheelImageView which is bound to the _wheelImageView instance variable.

```
@synthesize wheelImageView;
```

will create getters and setters bound to an ivar with the same name;

Comment: only setter will be called setWheelImageView