# Difference in synthesize property in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Code in .h file

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

Code in .m file

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
```

I'm a beginner in objective c , I wonder what is difference between  `@synthesize managedObjectContext; and @synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;` can some explain?

Comment: Thanks for those links, very useful Sorry i didn't looked that earlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@synthesize propertyName` creates a variable to back the property with the same name as the property, while `@synthesize propertyName = variableName` gives the variable an alternative name (perhaps the property name prefixed with an underscore).

Note that in the compilers shipped with the most recent version of Xcode using `@synthesize` is no longer necessary: the compiler figures out what properties need synthesizing, and implicitly inserts

```
@synthesize propertyName = _propertyName;
```

for each property that needs to be synthesized.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
```

you can write lines like this:

```
__managedObjectContext = someContext;
```

and it will change the value stored in this property by directly accessing it, without the setManagedObjectContext: method.

However, this line will be incorrect (unless you declare some other managedObjectContext before it):

```
managedObjectContext = someContext; //wrong
self.managedObjectContext = someContext; //good
```

P.S. Btw, [What exactly does @synthesize do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266467/what-exactly-does-synthesize-do)