# About naming the instance variable in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Sometimes we may explicitly specify the name of an instance variable in the `synthesize` statement, e.g.,

In `SomeViewController.h`,

```
//....
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject *variable;
//....
```

In `SomeViewController.m`,

```
//....
@synthesize variable = _variable;
//....
```

But why bother making this extra effort if the instance variable will be implicitly named as `_variable` even if we simply put it as:

```
@synthesize variable;
```

in the `SomeViewController.m`.

Can anyone share some idea on why it is necessary? Thank you :D

Comment: It's not necessary, that's the whole point of the compiler making that leap to underscored iVars.  Have you been reading the latest specs?

Comment: It's not. In fact, even the `@synthetize` is optional as of Xcode 4.4.

Comment: Btw: `@synthesize variable` is equivalent to `@synthesize variable = variable` *without* the leading underscore (to stay compatible with older compiler versions).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to avoid confusion (see comments): Using the `= _variable` part of the `@synthesize` is not required, nor is the `@synthesize` itself required any more.

This effort is only requied, when you want to link the property to a specific instance variable. With earlier Objective-C versions this part of the statement was required to set the name to something different from the property name, so when you want to call the iVar `_variable` and the property `variable`. The default would be `variable` (unlike your question). Without that `= something` ivar and property have the same name.

BTW, there is nothing wrong with using the same name for both. But having different names, a leading `_` would do, makes it more clear to the programmer whether he/she accesses the ivar directly or though the accessor methods. Sometimes this is of vast importance, especially when not using ARC. Therefore it helps avoiding errors.

With current Objective-C, however, you could omit the `@synthesize` statement at all and go with the defaults in that case. The default automatically synthesized instance `variable` name would have a leading `_` so `_variable` in your example.

Comment: Point taken. Thank you very much. But, by doing some simple experiment **in the earlier versions of Objective-C**, I can still send messages to `_variable`, even if we didn't declare `_variable` as `NSObject *_variable;` in `SomeViewController.h` (but there is a `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject *variable;` in `SomeViewController.h`, and there is a `@synthesize variable = _variable;` in `SomeViewController.m`. And by **current Objective-C**, do you mean Objective-C 2.0?

Comment: "With earlier Objective-C versions it was **required** to set the name to something different from the property name"? Before I was born?

Comment: @Flip, the wording may have been misleading. It was not required to set the name to something different. The question was whether the `"= something"` part of the `@synthesize` statement is nessessary or not. I responded to that question. An alterntaive wording fo the answer would be: "It is not required unless you wanted to use a different name for the ivar and the property". Hope that clarifies. (However, it could well be. Objective-C is older than you are.)

Comment: @congliu, frankly I am not quite sure when exactly it was introduced to Objective-C, that the `@synthesize` was optional. I used Obj-C 1992/93 and by then it was not optional unless you provided the getters and setters yourself along with all the memory management overhead etc. And now I am using it again since a 2 or 3 yeas (with different intensity) and all of a sudden from my piont of view, autosynthesizing saves some time and effort.

Comment: @congliu What you have to understand is that `@synthesize` is a compiler directive.  It doesn't matter how "early" a version of the language you use, so long as you have a sufficiently advanced version of GCC or CLANG.  The fact that you can message variables like that indicates you changed the SDK, but didn't bother to download and use an earlier version of the compiler.

Comment: @HermannKlecker Thanks for the clarification. History is always good to know :)

Comment: @Filip, thanks for asking. Misleading wordings aint helpful at all. I'll try to amend the wording.