# UITableView doesn't refresh when NSPredicate set

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nspredicate

Preface: I tried `[self.tableview reloadData]`. My app doesn't crash, but it doesn't refresh, either.

I'm trying to display 2 sets of results on one `TableViewController` depending upon whether an `NSPredicate` is set. I'm trying to find a jargon free answer how I can update a `UITableViewController` once a predicate is set.

My data displays properly the when the view initially loads. My predicate sets properly, all the log statements I've thrown in return values...but nothing happens when it's set.

I know this is a startlingly stupid question, but I'm too dumb figure it out. Every answer I've found involves a `UISearchBar`, deprecated methods, or is a snippet of an answer, etc.

**What I'd like to display:**

1) **A vanilla fetchRequest that displays everything--this works:** everything in my managedObjectContext which is set up in my `viewDidLoad` w/o an `NSPredicate`.

2) **Once I set an `NSPredicate`, I'd like to update the `tableView`--This doesn't crash, but it doesn't update the `tableView`**

On `MyTableViewController`, I have a popover which instantiates when I click a UIBarButtonItem on MyTableViewController. On the popover, I set a predicate on MyTableViewController.

Basically, I'd like to toggle what's displayed and that display toggle is driven by whether my variable is nil (everything displays) or filtered (variable sets a predicate).

I'm either the first or the dumbest person to attempt this feat of software engineering. I'll wager the latter, given how many times I've seen this as an end-user. **If you know what I'm doing wrong, I'd be grateful to hear from you.** Thank you for reading.

I have two entities: `PointOfInterest` and `LocationCategory`. I have a `UIBarButton` that triggers a popover of which `MyTableViewController` is a delegate. Clicking on the popover sets the `selectedCategory` property on `MyTableViewController`.:

```
// This gets set by PopoverTableViewController    
@property (nonatomic, strong) LocationCategory *selectedCategory;     

// This is set on `MyTableViewController`
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSPredicate *searchPredicate;
```

The property gets set correctly on `MyTableViewController`. I'm trying to use the `selectedCategory` object as the basis for a predicate to display "filtered" list of 'pointOfInterest' objects. I left out the boilerplate code from this `TVC`, but I've got the tableView delegate methods on the `TVC`.

I think I need to set my `fetchedResultsController` to nil and reinstantiate it w/ a predicate in my `refreshTableViewController` method. It doesn't crash, but it doesn't work, either.

Here's the `viewDidLoad` of `MyTableViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    NSLog(@"savedPOI managedObjectContext is %@", self.managedObjectContext);

    // Initialize fetch request
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"PointOfInterest"];

    // Add sort descriptors
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]]];

    // Initialize Fetched Results Controller
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    // Configure a fetchedResultsController
    [self.fetchedResultsController setDelegate:self];

    // Perform fetch
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to perform fetch");
        NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
    }

    // This sets up an observer that listens for when `selectedCategory` is set
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshTableViewController:) name:@"CategorySelected" object:nil];    
}
```

Once my `selectedCategory` is set, I have the following method set to run. It doesn't crash, but it doesn't refresh `MyTableViewController`. I suspect I've got a minor error here, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
- (void)refreshTableViewController:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ([[notification name]isEqualToString:@"CategorySelected"]) {
        NSLog(@"NSNotification on SavedPOITableViewController's self.selectedCategory is %@", self.selectedCategory.categoryName);

        // Nuke the cache that was loaded in viewDidLoad
        [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"PointOfInterest"];

        // Nuke the fetchedResultsController alloc/inited in viewDidLoad
        self.fetchedResultsController = nil;

        // Alloc init a new fetchRequest
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        // Set the entity
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PointOfInterest" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        // Add sort descriptors
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]]];

        // Reinstantiate the fetchedResultsController
            self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

        NSString *predicateString = self.selectedCategory.categoryName;
        NSLog(@"predicateString is %@", predicateString);

        self.searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"locationCategory.categoryName == %@", predicateString];
        NSLog(@"self.searchPredicate in refreshTableViewController is %@", predicateString);

        // Do the fetchRequest with the predicate
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:self.searchPredicate];

        // Perform fetch
        NSError *error = nil;
        [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to perform fetch");
            NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];        


    }
}
```

Just for completeness' sake, here's my `PointOfInterest` & `LocationCategory` classs:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class LocationCategory;

@interface PointOfInterest : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * note;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * phoneNumber;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * url;
@property (nonatomic, retain) LocationCategory *locationCategory;

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class PointOfInterest;

@interface LocationCategory : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) id categoryColor;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * categoryName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *pointOfInterest;
@end
```

Comment: Are you updating your tableview datasource? Please provide some relevant code regarding how your tableview is being populated specifically `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method body.

Comment: No. I have `fetchedResultsController` that's declared in the header and instantiated in `viewDidLoad`. All I'm trying to do is update the `fetchedResultsController` when there's a category selected.

Comment: But where are you binding your updated result to your table view?!

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Your `refreshTableViewController:` method effectively does nothing. Ask yourself this: "How is simply creating an instance of `NSFetchRequest` going to cause anything to change in the fetched results controller, much less in the table view?"

Comment: fetchedresultcontroller would only fetch data for you but it is your responsibility to bind that data to tableview cells UI for tableview to refresh. And for that, you need to implement tableview `dataSource` methods.

Comment: By the way `NSFetchRequest` is a readonly property of `NSFetchedResultsController`. Were you planning to modify it somehow?

Comment: I'm new to programming. I'm taking a class. This is part of my class. `MyTableViewController` displays data from `managedObjectContext` when the view initially loads. My mentor told me I needed ~5-6 lines of code to get it working for filtering. That's in my `refreshTVC` method. I know I'm missing something basic, but I'm still stumped as to what.

Comment: I'm not changing the question. Did I update the wording for added clarity? Yes. Did I change the substance of the question? No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

I added this to my implementation file on `MyTableViewController`:

```
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;
```

As I expected, I was missing something startlingly stupid--and **I was **RIGHT!!**

I read this post on Ray Wenderlich's website and I noticed it had that line in the implementation, but I didn't. I've never encountered the need to use `@synthesize` and I've seen mentions elsewhere that "you almost never need it", etc. Well, turns out, you do!

http://www.raywenderlich.com/14742/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-how-to-work-with-relations-and-predicates

This post on StackOverflow covers the basics of `@synthesize`.

[What exactly does @synthesize do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266467/what-exactly-does-synthesize-do)