# Displaying two sets of results in one TableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nspredicate

I know this is a startlingly stupid question, but I can't figure it out. Every answer involves a UISearchBar, which is not what I've got.

I'm trying to display 2 sets of results on one TableViewController.

**Results to display**

1) **everything** in my `managedObjectContext` which is set up in my `viewDidLoad`

2) a **filtered set** of results if a predicate is selected.

On `MyTableViewController`, I have a popover which instantiates when I click a `UIBarButtonItem` on `MyTableViewController`. On the popover, I set a predicate on `MyTableViewController`.

Basically, I'd like to toggle what's displayed and that display toggle is driven by whether my variable is `nil` (everything displays) or filtered (variable sets a predicate).

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: What you've written is more of a specification than a question.  It seems to me to be just a case of selecting the correct data source, either one that represents everything or one that only contains your selected subset of items.

Comment: I wrote a detailed question, but I'm not getting anything back. Above is the "physics for poets" version. Here's everything. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856403/uitableview-not-refreshing-despite-not-crashing-nslog-values-printing-properl

Comment: You can add something like this. Take a BOOL isSearchOn variable type and make it YES whenever your searchbar has some text.. In cellForRowAtIndex method just do  if(isSearchOn){} else {}. Same for number of rows or sections

Answer (score 1):

Have two NSArray properties `allValues` and `filteredValues`. Set up all your delegate/dataSource properties using your `filteredValues` array.

Next, do something like this when you first get all your data:

```
self.allValues = [someController fetchAllValues];
self.filteredValues = self.allValues;
[self.myView.tableView reloadData];
```

Last, alter your `filteredValues` array whether or not a predicate is selected:

```
if (self.selectedPredicate) {
    self.filteredValues = [self.allValues filteredArrayUsingPredicate:self.selectedPredicate];
} else {
    self.filteredValues = self.allValues;
}
[self.myView.tableView reloadData];
```