# @property hides _ivar when setter and getter are custom

Tags: objective-c

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (strong, readwrite, nonatomic) NSNumber *currentNumber;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (NSNumber *)currentNumber {



}

- (void)setCurrentNumber:(NSNumber *)currentNumber {

}
```

1. Why I can't access _currentNumber in currentNumber?
2. If I will remove setCurrentNumber then I can access _currentNumber in currentNumber?

Comment: __1.__ because _both_ setter and getter are custom; __2.__ yes, you can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@property` does not cause the ivar generation; rather, it's the implicit `@synthesize`.  However, when you implement both the getter and setter, there is nothing to (implicitly) synthesize, so clang doesn't bother.  If you add an explicit `@synthesize` statement, you'll get your ivar.

Answer (score 1):

Like *Avi* mentioned, there is `@synthesize` keyword. If you just declare property(without implementing getter and setter for it) the corresponding ivar will be generated. Its name will be [underscore][property_name].For example declaring `@property currentNumber;` leads to implicit applying `@synthesize currentNumber = _currentNumber;
But if you want to assign ivar with another name to your property you can declare this ivar and synthesize the property with it:

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
{
     NSNumber *_anotherIvar;
}
@property (strong, readwrite, nonatomic) NSNumber *currentNumber;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize currentNumber = _anotherIvar;
@end
```

@synthesize tells the compiler to create corresponding getter and setter which are backed by ivar on the right side of assignment. And if you provide your own setter - you prevent compiler from creating implicit synthesize(and generating ivar), so you need to provide ivar by yourself somehow(for example use explicit synthesize).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3269636/3014519) is good explanation about @synthesize.