# What will @synthesize do when "get" implementation provided?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have already read up on `@synthesize` and found some really great information on this question: [What exactly does @synthesize do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266467/what-exactly-does-synthesize-do) and I understand the difference between an instance variable and a property, but in the code I inherited, my problem goes a little further than that and I would like to know what it does (or if it's necessary) in the following circumstance.  If more code context is needed just ask.

```
// example.h
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;    

// example.m
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;

//... later on in example.m
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {        
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

So in the example from the linked answer `MapView` and `MapView1` were both defined in the `.h` file whereas in my example, a pointer to  `_managedObjectContext` is never defined as far as I can tell after doing a global search.  We're using it with the `@synthesize` keyword as well as providing a concrete definiton of `managedObjectContext` in the implementation file.

So my question is really 2:

1. Is `@synthesize` even doing anything here?
2. Why does it still compile when `_managedObjectContext` isn't defined like in the other example question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, as you've provided the *getter* for the property.
2. Because the property provides a default backing instance variable called `_managedObjectContext`.

Note: there is no need to `@synthesize` at all these days.

Comment: So when I declare a property `managedObjectContext`, the compiler automatically creates an ivar called `_managedObjectContext`?  So in my example I could simply write the `managedObjectContext` implementation as `return [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];` and the compiler takes care of the rest?  Are there any memory leak types of things I should worry about when doing this?

Comment: @akousmata Well not quite as your getter is kinda special.  I think you should dump it and allocate that object in the `init` method instead.  Much more conventional.

Comment: I'll try to look into that, not sure I can without breaking a bunch of other things.  Thanks for the info.  Still quite new to iOS

Answer (score 0):

In today's framework you don't need to `@synthesize`. `Property` will auto synthesize by the framework.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Also I would be careful with the word "framework" as that has a special meaning in Objective-C programming.

Comment: yeah, you are right i think. I used wrong word framework. but i was talking in different sense. I am not mean framework in context of objective c.!!

Comment: as pointed out above, this answer is both unhelpful and wrong. -1.